# htpasswd coflicting with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, .htpasswd

When I try to add AuthType my site does not work when I enter my password.
Do you know what is wrong?

I am getting error 500. But without AuthType it works

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Options All -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1\.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$1/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^en/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^pl/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^pl [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lib/sendmail.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.xml [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pl [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lib/sendmail.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.xml [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pl%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Your question contradicts itself: first you say that adding `AuthType` breaks your site, then you state that "it works". Now what?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile: _"[The] File-path [argument] is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the ServerRoot."_ - are you sure `AuthUserFile .htpasswd` is referring to the correct location?

Answer (score -1):

Reference https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype

AuthType can only be enclosed in a `<Directory>` statement, or in a .htaccess file.  So you must specify a directory, like this:

```
<Directory "/www/htdocs">

    YOUR AUTH CONFIGURATION HERE

</Directory>
```

It is not allowed to have it like you did.  If you want to protect your entire site with this, you can setup your `<Directory>` clause on the same directory as your `DocumentRoot` value.

Comment: _"or in a .htaccess file"_ - I didn't see any indication that that would _not_ be the context of the question here.

Comment: Enclode doesn't work in ".htaccess file"

Comment: The context for AuthType does mention directory, .htaccess.